# My program does not count the vowels. Could you tell me why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/*Variables are listed below*/ 
int main() {
    int i=0, j=0, k=0,a, minIndex=0,maxIndex=0,max=0, min=0;
    int c=0, count=0;
    int Vowel(char ch);
    char countries[100],lWords[100][100];

/*Words counting code*/
    printf("***WORD LENGTH AND VOWELS COUNTER PROGRAM***\n");
    printf(" Output the number of vowels in both words\n");
    printf("***ENTER 10 COUNTRIES FROM THE LIST BELOW AS INPUT:\n");
    printf(" ARGENTINA, AUSTRALIA, BRAZIL, CANADA, CHINA, FRANCE, GERMANY, INDIA, INDONESIA, ITALY,JAPAN/n");
    printf("REPUBLIC OF KOREA, MEXICO, RUSSIA, SAUDI ARABIA, SOUTH AFRICA, TURKEY, UK, USA\n");
    gets(countries);


    while(countries[k]!='\0')
    {
        j=0;
        while(countries[k]!=' '&&countries[k]!='\0')
        {
            lWords[i][j]=countries[k];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        lWords[i][j]='\0';
        i++;
        if(countries[k]!='\0')
        {
            k++;
        }
    }

    int length=i;
    max=strlen(lWords[0]);
    min=strlen(lWords[0]);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
       a=strlen(lWords[i]);
       if(a>max)
        {
            max=a;
            maxIndex=i;
        }
        if(a<min)
        {
            min=a;
            minIndex=i;
        }
    }
      while(countries[k]!='\0');
       {

   /* Vowels counting code is written below*/   
int  Vowel (char ch){
scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch =='o' || ch=='O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
      count++;
    c++;
  }

printf("/n The largest word is: %s\n", lWords[maxIndex]);
printf("/n The number of vowels in the string '%s' is: %d\n", lWords[maxIndex],count);
printf("/n The smallest word is: %s\n",lWords[maxIndex]);
printf("/n The number of vowels in the string '%s' is: %d\n", lWords[minIndex],count);
       }
    return 0;
}
```

Write a program that gets a list of words from the user as input and outputs the largest and the smallest word provided. Your solution also must output the number of vowels in both words. type 10 countries from the list below as input: Argentina, Australia, Brazil, Canada, China, France, Germany, India,
Indonesia, Italy, Japan, Republic of Korea, Mexico, Russia, Saudi Arabia, South
Africa, Turkey, UK, USA.

The first part of the code is working properly that identifies the largest and smallest countries when I list 10 countries. However, it does not count vowels in the words which gives zero vowels for 'Brazil' instead of 2 vowels. What do I need to add or change in the code?

Comment: Have you actually attempted to debug the problem? Run the program in a debugger, step through it line by line and watch the variables as it runs to find where things start to go wrong.

Comment: Lots of problems. You define a function `Vowel` but never actually call it anywhere. `while(countries[k]!='\0');` the semicolon terminates the loop which means it has no body. `k` is not set back to `0` before that second `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you never count the vowels. You wrote a function for that (`Vowel()`) but never used it. Anyway the function contains the statement `c++` which is out of place ...because we are using `C`. I am kidding, it just doesn't make any sense. Even the `scanf` shouldn't be there because you pass the character as argument.

Also I advise you to put both the prototype and the declaration of `Vowel()` outside of the `main()`

That said, I am giving you a function to count the vowels in a word, you can make a similar one to check if one character is a vowel, or to check whether a given string matches one of the countries.

```
int howManyVowels( char *s )
{
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int count = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++) if( strchr(vowels, s[i]) ) ++count;
    
    return count;
}
```

Have fun.

EDIT: *"I replaced the code above with yours but it is still same. Also, I put vowel decleration outside of the main."*

You can't just put my function in your program. Your program needs a function checking whether a character is a vowel, not a function that gives the number of vowels in a word. I gave you the function as an example to help you make yours. Here's a sample program which uses my function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

int howManyVowels( char *s );

int main() {

    char word[SIZE], longest[SIZE], shortest[SIZE];
    int len, max = 0, min = SIZE;
    
    while( scanf(" %s", word) == 1 ) {
        
        if( max < (len = strlen(word)) ) {
            
            max = len;
            strcpy(longest, word);
        }
        else if( min > len ) {
            
            min = len;
            strcpy(shortest, word);
        }
    }
    
    printf("The longest one was %s, which has %d vowels.\nThe shortest was %s, which has %d vowels.\n", longest, howManyVowels(longest), shortest, howManyVowels(shortest));

    return 0;
}

int howManyVowels( char *s )
{
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int count = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++) if( strchr(vowels, s[i]) ) ++count;
    
    return count;
}
```

However the program doesn't check if the word is one of the countries. I suggest you to take my function just as an example to build the function that your program needs, i.e. a function telling whether a character is a vowel or not. And you can also take it as example to build a function checking whether a given word matches one of the countries.

Comment: int  Vowel (char ch){
scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch =='o' || ch=='O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
      count++;
    c++;
  }             Thank you for your response, I replaced the code above with yours but it is still same. Also, I put vowel decleration outside of the main.